# command line to set default browser application doesn't work in v 21.10

Tags: command-line, 21.10, default-browser

I previously performed a bash call in v 20.10 to set my custom browser as default. I used
`xdg-settings set default-web-browser mybrowser.desktop`
which does not work in v 21.10

I tried
`sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`
which returned

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x-www-browser
```

I tried
`export BROWSER=mybrowser.desktop`
in .bashrc which also did not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `update-alternatives --query x-www-browser` return? Probably the same, so that would mean no browsers are announced to the debian alternatives system.

Comment: It might be wise to show your `mybrowser.desktop`. The issue with xdg-settings might be there.

Comment: '''Name: x-www-browser
Link: /usr/bin/x-www-browser
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/vivaldi-stable
Value: /usr/bin/vivaldi-stable

Alternative: /usr/bin/chromium-browser
Priority: 40

Alternative: /usr/bin/vivaldi-stable
Priority: 200
'''

Comment: do you mean the contents of mybrowser.desktop? It is: ''' [Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=myBrowser
Comment=Custom browser
Exec=/home/maxx/myBrowser/myBrowser %F
Path=/home/maxx/myBrowser
Icon=/home/maxx/myBrowser/myBrowser.ico
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=WebBrowser; '''

Comment: Looks good: the ` %F` indeed should probably be there - I was wondering if that was perhaps missing.

Comment: **Thanks for your responses.** This is a challenge. They made a lot of changes to 21.10, so I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem today, and I have yet to find the correct command line to achieve the desired result. I did finally get the default changed.

For me it was under preferences, LXQt settings, LXQt configuration center. Once in the configuration center open file associations to find the default applications tab. Select the browser you prefer, and that's it. Hope this helps..